# Set Entity Framework one-to-one mapping with non primary key field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BlogDetail BlogDetail { get; set; }
}

public class BlogDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

There is a one-to-one relationship between Blog and BlogDetail and the foreign key is Blog.Id to BlogDetail.BlogId.

BlogDetail.BlogId is a unique constraint to enforce the one-to-one relationship.

The BlogDetail.Id column is necessary because another table will refer to BlogDetail as a one-to-many.

I've added the following mappings:

```
public BlogMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);

    Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}

public BlogDetailMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);

    Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    HasRequired(t => t.Blog).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.BlogId);
}
```

I am trying to get EF 6 to generate the correct sql query using none primary key field as a key to no avail. It gives me the following sql query:

```
select * 
from Blog
left join BlogDetail on Blog.BlogDetail_Id = BlogDetail.Id
```

In reality what I need is:

```
select * 
from Blog
left join BlogDetail on Blog.Id = BlogDetail.BlogId
```

Does anyone know how to achieve a one to one mapping using a non primary key field in EF? I've tried everything possible to no avail.

If it helps I will have another table dangling off BlogDetail:

```
public class BlogDetailSupplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BlogDetailId { get; set; }

    public BlogDetail BlogDetail { get; set; }
}
```

This is why BlodDetail must have an ID PK column and a briefId FK column. Standard normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this is what you want:

```
public BlogMap()
{
    HasOptional(b => b.BlogDetail).WithOptionalPrincipal(bd => bd.Blog);
}
```

This way `BlogDetail` will have a `BlogId` foreignkey while maintaining it's own (identity) Id field that you can use in your one-to-many relationship.

**Update 1**

Created a new project with the following model and I was able to achieve what you asked in your question by applying the above mapping:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BlogDetail BlogDetail { get; set; }
}

public class BlogDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostCount { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogDetail> BlogDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasOptional(b => b.BlogDetail).WithOptionalPrincipal(bd => bd.Blog);
    }
}

public class ContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext db)
    {
        var blog1 =  new Blog { Name = "Blog 1", BlogDetail = new BlogDetail { PostCount = 10 } };
        var blog2 =  new Blog { Name = "Blog 2", BlogDetail = new BlogDetail { PostCount = 28 } };

        db.Blogs.AddRange(new List<Blog> { blog1, blog2 });
    }
}
```

Here you can see the query and it's results:

[image: Screenshot]

And here are the tables:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Did you actually try this? It doesn't work and produces an even crazier query with three joins to blogdetail and looks to join on blog_id which doesn't work.

Comment: I have this same situation you are facing in one of my models and it's working as intended. Maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: This isn't an answer to my original question. What you've done is used code first which naturally generates FK fields as _Id, in this case blog_id which i can clearly see from your "answer". We are NOT using code first and are using mapping to map to an already existing database. We need the field on BlogDetail to be called BlogId and not Blog_id which Code first generates. I'm not doing anything wrong and I suggest you reread the original question i posted.

Comment: Wow... you are quite arrogant for someone asking for help. The code first part of my answer was just to provide proof that the mapping works. My "answer" (as you refered to) would still be good for you with a simple .Map() to set the the field name to ``BlogId``. Sorry for trying to help you, I'll remember not to try again.

Comment: @HenriqueMiranda Your fix seems to "work" in the sense that it provides a "0..1 to 0..1" relationship and won't require the shared primary key which EF's fluent API leverages for the 1 to 0..1 relationships.  However, I believe the original post wanted the latter (1 to 0..1), in which case EF will force the shared PK on the dependent entity and also make it the FK.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva He wants exactly what I've done, but he only needs the mapping and he wants to set a custom FK field's name. Except for the field naming, it's all there and naming the field is the easiest part but I'm done with this guy and won't bother to make another edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on the object

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Entity()entity.HasOne().WithOne().HasForeignKey(x=>x.BlogId);
}

VERY important!!
when you do the query, _context.Blog.Include(inc=>inc.BlogDetail)

Don't forget the INCLUDE or the objects will be null!!

Answer (score -1):

With these maps:

```
public BlogMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);
}

public BlogDetailMap()
{
    HasKey(t => t.Id);

    HasRequired(t => t.Blog)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.BlogId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

This produces nearly the result your after:

```
MyContext.BlogDetails.Includes(x => x.Blogs);
```

The select is on BlogDetails and joins in Blogs using the Ids your after.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[title] AS [title], 
    [Extent1].[BlogId] AS [BlogId], 
    [Extent2].[id] AS [id1], 
    [Extent2].[title] AS [title1], 
    [Extent2].[BlogDetail_id] AS [BlogDetail_id]
    FROM  [dbo].[BlogDetails] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[BlogId] = [Extent2].[id]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's something simple that I've already tried and does not work. It ends up producing a query with a join of Blog.Id = BlogDetail.Id. The problem is that EF uses the primary keys of both tables as the joins which isn't correct.

Comment: Well, that's how one-to-one relationships works. The dependant's Id is defined by it's principal's Id.

Comment: I added some more info to the answer about doing the join in linq.

Comment: I know how to do the join in linq but that's not what i want. The foreign Key field on the BlogDetail table does not necessarily have to be the key of the BlogDetail table.

Comment: Another update, and after digging I realized you are doing the mapping correctly, which is insane, but oh wells. I just had to add WillCascadeOnDelete(false) for it to work.

Comment: Afraid you're wrong again Fredrik. MyContext.BlogDetails.Includes(x => x.Blogs) is my test code but this requires the mapping to be correct in the first place. It will not produce the sql you've posted above. I've tried every combination of mapping possible and it will not work.

Comment: That is messed up. I added the mappings that gives me the desired query.

Comment: There are no mappings on the post - you just added the lambda and the sql output. The mappings produce the sql from the lambda.

Comment: They dissapeard of into cyberspace. I have added them again. If that doesn't work, then for informations sake, I use SQL Express 2012, and EF 6.0.2 from Nuget.

Comment: The mapping you've added is a direct copy of my original question but this does not work. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: It's bound to be something because of different environments then. If it helps further I'm on Windows 8.1, VS 2013, and added to my comment above, SQL Express 2012, and EF 6.0.2 from Nuget. Good luck in hunting down the reason it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, VS2012 and EF 6.0.2. The version of sql server and vs are pretty much irrelevant as it's EF that does all the mapping.

Comment: I've just noticed the bit about WillCascadeOnDelete(false) so will try that